# How to solve a homogenous recurrence with a characteristic polynomial of degree 4?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

We have the following recurrence:

$t_{n}=\begin{cases}n\\ 2t_{n-1}-2t_{n-3}+t_{n-4}\end{cases}$

if $n= 0$ or $1$ then $t_n = n$ else it's $2t_{n-1}-2t_{n-3}+t_{n-4}$.

The homogenous recurrence is $t_n - 2t_{n-1}+2t_{n-3}-t_{n-4} = 0$

The characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^4 -2x^3 + 2x - 1$

In the provided solutions for this exercise they verify if $p(1)$ and $p(-1)$ are 
$= 0$ before carrying with a long division of $p(x)$ with $(x^2 - 1)$. The reason for this is if $p(1)$ and $p(-1)$ are indeed roots (meaning causes $p(x)$ to equal $0$) then we have $p(x) = (x - 1)(x + 1)q(x) = (x^2 - 1)q(x)$.

Therefore we use long division to find $q(x)$ so we can find the remainding roots.

What is not clear to me is how did they known that 1 and -1 could potentially be roots before verifing it? Is it a common pattern for solving questions like these. Should I conclude that we always should check for 1 and -1 as roots. What if they're not roots, what do we do then?

Comment: How did they know that $\pm 1$ could potentially be roots? By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)! The divisors of $-1$ are $\pm 1$. So you should check for divisors of $a_n$ in general, if $f(x)=x^n+\cdots +a_n$.

Comment: In other words, this step doesn't have anything to do with recurrence relations—it's just an algebraic method. Side note: since you have a degree-4 recurrence, you need 4 values specified at the beginning—right now it seems you've specified only 2 such values.